# writing the output to a text file using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a series of line to a text file using Java.

Code:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true);
for (first for loop) {
            for (second for loop) {
                if (condition TRUE){
                    writer.write(element1 + element2.toString()+"\n");
                }
                else {
                writer.write("-"+ element1 + element2.toString()+"\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

Error:

Only an empty file is getting created. Please, any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Can you give us your actual code?  Using `FileWriter` is fine, you do need to close it though.

Comment: @jnbbender thanks for your time the given answer solved it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true);
```

with:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
```

and in the end:

```
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the snippet you provided. The problem could be that, the `conditions` in your `for` loops and `if` statements are never met. Thus your code never gets to

`writer.write(element1 + element2.toString()+"\n");`.

So to be able to help on that unless you provide the actual code.

Also you must ensure that `file.txt` exist. It would be better if you use an absolute path like `C:\\Users\\YOUNG MILLIE\\Documents\\file.txt` in windows environment.

Because i tried with this example and it works fine.

```
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\YOUNG MILLIE\\Documents\\file.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100;i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 50;k++) {
                if (i <=50 ){
                    writer.write(k +"\n");
                }
                else {
                    writer.write("-"+ k +"\n");
                }
            }
        }
        writer.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how the code should look like and you can substitute your logic wherever applicable.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteAFile {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String element1="First Element";
        Integer element2=10;
        FileWriter writer = null;

        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(new File("file.txt"), true);

            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
                    if (true){ //Write the condition here
                        writer.write(element1 + element2.toString()+"\n");
                    }
                    else {
                        writer.write("-"+ element1 + element2.toString()+"\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```